# What time of day does the Bounty Board reset?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

The bounty board cycles all quests and contracts on it once per day.

Does anyone know what time that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounty board changes at [9:00am UTC](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/Vermintide/comments/58g84l/quest_and_contract_refresh_time/).  For me, that's 4:00am on the East Coast of America (5:00am with daylight saving time).

Though it's just a Reddit source, I've confirmed that this is the time.

[Additional Steam source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/235540/discussions/1/333656722962218141/).